# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined on full calendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I have problem with full calendar, im using laravel framework. im try to showing data in my tabel to full calendar but showing error.

> Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

This Is My Controller

```
public function calendarmodul()
{
    $caledarmodul = Modul::all();
    return $caledarmodul;
}
```

This is My view

```
 $(function () {  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        {
          url: "{{ url('calendar-modul') }}",
          type:"GET",
          dataType: "JSON",
          error: function() 
          {
            alert("error");
          },
          success: function()
          {
              console.log("successfully loaded");
          }
        }
    ],
    editable  :false,
    droppable :false,
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are providing wrong parameters for **full calendar**.
Your JSON data should look something like this:

```
    {
      title: 'Event Title1',
      start: '2015-03-17T13:13:55.008',
      end: '2015-03-19T13:13:55.008'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event Title2',
      start: '2015-03-17T13:13:55-0400',
      end: '2015-03-19T13:13:55-0400'
    }
```

Console log your response and check it matches the format for full calendar.

Also return your response as json

```
return json_encode($data);
```

To select custom fields, you can do something like:

```
$data = Modul::select('name as title', 'start_date as start', 'end_date as end'->get();
```